# Scala: upper bound [T <: AnyRef] does not allow to return [AnyRef]

Tags: scala

I'm trying to express the following idea:
Function `caseClassFields` should return an array of `(String, T)` pairs, by processing a case class.
I put upper bound for `T`, expecting that it should be a subtype of `AnyRef` or `AnyRef` itself.

Here is a function:

```
def caseClassFields[T <: AnyRef](obj: AnyRef): Array[(String, T)] = {
  val metaClass = obj.getClass
  metaClass.getDeclaredFields.map {
    field => {
      field.setAccessible(true)
      (field.getName, field.get(obj))
    }
  }
}
```

But unfortunately I get following error:

Expression of type `Array[(String, AnyRef)]` doesn't conform to expected type `Array[(String, T)]`

How to fix this?

Comment: Beware: `Array` is invariant (because of Java interoperability). Use a Scala collection instead (`Vector`, `List` ...).

Comment: Actually, it doesn't help in this case :(

Comment: `field.get` returns `AnyRef`. Why do you need `T` here at all?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov because then I try to apply the `validator` function to the elements: `case class FieldRule[T <: AnyRef](fieldName: String, validator: T => Boolean, errorMsg: String)`

Comment: Probably I do something wrong from the design point of view :(

Comment: If you want to explore the case class fields in a type safe way, consider looking at [*shapeless*](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)

Comment: You might want to look at `LabelledGeneric` in shapeless https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you probably want to use shapeless, but to elaborate.

The method `field.get()` isnt related to the type parameter. Normally you would use a type parameter like this

```
def caseClassFields[T <: AnyRef](obj: T): Array[(String, T)] = ???
```

or this ..

```
def caseClassFields[T <: AnyRef](obj: Container[T]): Array[(String, T)] = ???
```

If there was some link between `field.get` and `T` it could work, but the relationship would need to be proven to the compiler. As the `T` can be anything the compiler cant prove anything about it.

I can strongly recommend this book the 'Type Astronaut’s Guide to Shapeless' as a intro to the topic.

http://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Answer (score 4):

Doing what you want with reflection and keeping type safety are orthogonal requirements. But [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless), a library for generic derivation, can do what you want and still keep you type safe.

Here's a short example using shapeless to get you started.

We first define our algebra:

```
sealed trait ValidatableField

case class ValidatableString(value: Boolean)
    extends ValidatableField

case class ValidatableInt(value: Boolean) extends ValidatableField

case class ValidatableRecord(fields: List[(String, ValidatableField)])
    extends ValidatableField
```

Now we define our validator trait:

```
trait Validator[T] {
  def validate(value: T): ValidatableField
}

trait RecordValidator[T] extends Validator[T] {
  def validate(value: T): ValidatableRecord
}
```

Now lets define, for the sake of the example, validation on `Int` and `String`:

```
implicit val intValidator = new Validator[Int] {
  override def validate(t: Int): ValidatableField = ValidatableInt(t > 42)
}

implicit val stringValidator = new Validator[String] {
  override def validate(t: String): ValidatableField = ValidatableString(t.length < 42)
}
```

Now we define a generic implementation for `HList` which will cover our `ValidatableRecord` which is the generic representation of our case class:

```
implicit val hnilEncoder: RecordValidator[HNil] = new RecordValidator[HNil] {
  override def validate(value: HNil): ValidatableRecord = ValidatableRecord(Nil)
} 

implicit def hlistValidator[K <: Symbol, H, T <: HList](
  implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K],
  hEncoder: Lazy[Validator[H]],
  tEncoder: RecordValidator[T]
): RecordValidator[FieldType[K, H] :: T] = {
  val fieldName = witness.value.name
  new RecordValidator[::[FieldType[K, H], T]] {
    override def validate(value: ::[FieldType[K, H], T]): ValidatableRecord = {
      val head = hEncoder.value.validate(value.head)
      val tail = tEncoder.validate(value.tail)
      ValidatableRecord((fieldName, head) :: tail.fields)
    }
  }
}

implicit def genericEncoder[A, H <: HList](
  implicit generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, H],
  hEncoder: Lazy[RecordValidator[H]]): Validator[A] = {
    new RecordValidator[A] {
      override def validate(value: A): ValidatableRecord =
        hEncoder.value.validate(generic.to(value))
  }
}
```

With this much code, we can now validate any case class which has a `String` and `Int` field in it, and it is trivial to add other validator for more primitives:

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    case class Foo(s: String, i: Int)
    val foo = Foo("hello!", 42)
    println(Validator[Foo].validate(foo))
  }
}
```

Yields:

```
ValidatableRecord(List((s,ValidatableString(true)), (i,ValidatableInt(false))))
```

I know this can be overwhelming a bit, but [David Gurnells "Guide To Shapeless"](https://github.com/davegurnell/shapeless-guide) is a great place to get started.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this comprehensive example!

Comment: @AlexFruzenshtein You welcome. Ask further questions as you go, shapeless is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is `field.get(obj)` returns `AnyRef` while your return type is `T`. Therefore, you need to convert it into `T`. However, I don't see any use of `Generic type T` in your code, so you can simply change the return type to `Array[(String, AnyRef)]`.

```
def caseClassFields[T <: AnyRef](obj: AnyRef): Array[(String, AnyRef)]
```

However, if you insist to use Generic, you need to convert `field.get(obj)` to type `T`. Note, that you might get exception in case of invalid type while converting to type `T`.

```
  def caseClassFields[T <: AnyRef](obj: AnyRef): Array[(String, T)] = {
    val metaClass = obj.getClass
    metaClass.getDeclaredFields.map {
      field => {
        field.setAccessible(true)
        (field.getName, field.get(obj).asInstanceOf[T])
      }
    }
  }
  case class Foo(name:String)

  val result:Array[(String, String)] = caseClassFields[String](Foo("bar"))
```